# Discovering proxy servers on a private network

Tags: windows, linux, networking, proxy

Suppose that I am in a **private network of computers** (say each having ip addresses 192.168.*.* ). Some of the machines( we have no information regarding their ip, name and no physical access to the servers) in the network are connected to internet and they **run an http proxy at some port** say 3128.
 *Is there a program which can be run on Windows or Linux which will give me the list of machines(ip addresses and ports if possible) acting as proxy servers?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nmap](http://nmap.org/) is your friend, just scan your selected ip range for those squid(and some others) servers running on 3128. A few more common ports to scan for are 8080, 80, 8888, 6588.

You could also take the approach of researching the machines on the network with nmap and then look into the most common proxy server software for that operating system, then narrowing the scan down port-wise to the specific IP of the most common server operating systems returned. This will speed up your results, without scanning random IP's for the service. But, if you are looking for rogue IP's on your internal network then this approach is not for you, as you would want to cover the most ground at one time.

**Discalimer:** If you don't have permission to scan the network or don't have a reason to do so legally, you may find that you will raise some red flags with your intended actions.

Comment: I have tried nmap before and it worked. But didnt know that it supports a range of ip addresses. Will try it now :)

Comment: You could try 192.168.0.0/16 to start then move up from there.